# Help understanding SQL Server Developer License when users test via webserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, testing, license, development

I'm trying to understand how many licenses I may need if we decide to pursue a SQL Server Developer license for our Testing environment.

We would have 5 actual developer and DBA's physically accessing the database to perform work.

The part where I get confused is our users will be testing our applications from a web server. This webserver will communicate with a 'logic' server that will perform all the database interaction.

At our highest level of testing we probably have 20 users on the system, but depending on the time of year they may be different users.  Example: During fiscal year end we may have 20 people from account on the system, but during benefit enrollment time of year we may have 20 HR/Payroll users testing on the system.

In reading different sets of documentation[(Article 1)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/C/73CAD4E0-D0B5-4BE5-AB49-D5B886A5AE00/SQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf)[(Article 2)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f40a273-a928-4e05-93e3-b4196283a1a4/sql-server-license-for-developer-edition) and speaking to our license reseller I still do not have a clear idea of how many licenses I need.

I think I can purchase 5 for the actual developers/DBA's and one license for each SQL accounts the services uses?

This is the how we are structured currently.  The servers have SQL Server accounts for authentication[image].

Comment: According to the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 quick licensing reference, use of multiplexing devices to circumvent the need for user licenses is not valid.  Each and every person accessing a Developer Edition instance needs to be licensed for Developer Edition (or MSDN Professional+).  http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/4/A/64A1EC8F-F575-41E1-9D34-821FA9F98F8E/SQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf

Comment: @MaxVernon - Thanks. Do you know how this is handled with employee turnover?  If we buy 60 licenses for the dev box, but have turnover throughout the year (which is very common), but all the access is done via-multiplexing I'm not sure how to track active licenses for the year?

Comment: If you have 60 licenses and at most 60 people simultaneously using the server, I don't think Microsoft would have any issue with that.  Now,  if you were using the server for production data in ANY way, they would have an issue regardless of the number of Developer Edition licenses.  The best advice for this is contact Microsoft and ask them.